# How to redirect one version of url to another in express node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have following implementation already done

```
app.post('/k/v4/monitor/start', function (req, res) {
      Monitor.start(data, function (err) {
            res.end('Monitor Started');
      });
});

app.post('/k/v4/monitor/stop', function (req, res) {
      Monitor.start(data, function (err) {
            res.end('Monitor Stopped');
      });
});
```

Now requirement is I need to support few older version (1 to 3) and redirect to version 4. That means /k/v1/monitor/*, /k/v2/monitor/*, /k/v3/monitor/* all urls should be redirected to /k/v4/monitor/*.

How to handle such case of routing in express? What is the best possible ways to achieve this? If anyone can provide me an example it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use HTTP redirects:

```
app.post('/k/v1/monitor/start', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHeader(301, { 'Location' : '/k/v4/monitor/start'});
    res.end();
})
```

But as I understood the problem is that the POST request is changed to GET upon the redirect. So I don't know if you can use this solution. Or maybe you don't need to use HTTP POST at all, you can just use HTTP GET (it would mean using app.get instead of app.post for all related URLs) ....

Comment: I need to use HTTP post to get post data from client!

Comment: Actually I was looking for a common logic at one place. to redirect all lower version urls to v4

Comment: Maybe 'redirect' is not the right word in this case. Can you just use regular expressions for the URL path? So you can use '/k/v[1234]/monitor/start' instead of '/k/v4/monitor/start'. That way the mapping will handle all versions...